# Polling for specific time in the future

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

So i've been programming a little talking AI thing in python 2.7 on the raspberry pi and i've come across an error!

I'm trying to set up an alarm function so you set the time you want it to wake you up then it plays a song at that time and then after reads out a set message. I've got the code pretty far and it was working perfectly fine earlier but suddenly it's stopped working and i can't figure out why. It feels like it's skipping the while loop but i'm really not sure!

Heres the code, ignore the 'speak' command that's just to make it talk.

```
if userInput == "set alarm":
            alarmnow = datetime.datetime.now()
            espeak.synth("What hour would you like to set the alarm?")
            hour = raw_input("What hour would you like to set the alarm?: ")
            espeak.synth("What minute would you like to set the alarm?")
            minute = raw_input("What minute would tou like to set the alarm?: ")
            espeak.synth("What would you like me to say after the alarm?")
            message = raw_input("What would you like me to say after the alarm?: ")
            while alarmnow.hour != int(hour) and alarmnow.minute != int(minute):
                    time.sleep(1)
            os.system("omxplayer takemetochurch.mp3")
            espeak.synth(message)
            print(message)
```

Please help me it's really annoying me, I've been working on it for so long and I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Comment: Is this a typo? `minute = raw_input("What minute would tou like to set the alarm$`

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow!  your source code lines seem to be cut off at the end (`$`s suddenly), and hence, we can't analyze it. Also, please come up with a more descriptive title!

Comment: The $ at the end is just because I copied it directly from the raspberry pi and it goes off screen but the that bit of code is correct it just ends with ?: ")

Comment: You need to keep reading the time. Right now you just grab it at the top so any alarm more than a minute in the future will take 24 hours to hit again. Do `datetime.datetime.now()` in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you never update 'now' so your clock will poll forever. You could rework your while loop to get the time on each loop.

But you should avoid polling when you can. Its inefficient and there is a risk you miss your window if something else is going on in the system. That's unlikely in your case because you only have to hit within the minute ... except when daylight savings time hits and you miss it completely.

Since you already have hours and minutes and they are easily converted to seconds, just sleep the full time

```
if userInput == "set alarm":
            espeak.synth("What hour would you like to set the alarm?")
            hour = raw_input("What hour would you like to set the alarm?: ")
            espeak.synth("What minute would you like to set the alarm?")
            minute = raw_input("What minute would tou like to set the alarm?: ")
            espeak.synth("What would you like me to say after the alarm?")
            message = raw_input("What would you like me to say after the alarm?: ")
            # setup alarm for today but if its already past, go to tomorrow
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            nominate = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day,
                int(hour), int(minute))
            if nominate < now:
                nominate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            time.sleep((nominate - now).seconds)
            os.system("omxplayer takemetochurch.mp3")
            espeak.synth(message)
            print(message)
```

Comment: I agree with the comment about polling, but you should use the hour and minute to calculate the difference, and then wait for that long. This will only work if it's exactly midnight.

Comment: This is the best answer in my humble opinion. You do not just identify the issue in the OP's code but are able to step back and realize that there is a much better solution to the problem entirely that the other answers fundamentally missed. That said, @Gijs

Comment: @Gijs - you are right, i kinda mis-read the question. I'll supply an edit.

Comment: This didn't work, it just sleeps and doesn't stop at the time i chose

Comment: @JamesBall - gijs pointed out the error. I'll write up a fix and have it in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate the help!

Comment: I updated the answer to set the alaram for today but if thats already in the past, set it for tomorrow.

Comment: That's great Thanks but, this error -  nominate = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day,
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: @JamesBall: That was a typo.  When you define `now`, say `now = datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: YAY! IT WORKS! Thank you so much @tdelaney i'm actually so happy! Finally i can move on with the code!

Comment: yeah, I missed that when typing it in. it should be `datetime.datetime.now(). I'm bating 1000 today.

Answer (score 0):

```
message = raw_input("What would you like me to say after the alarm?: ")
alarmnow = datetime.datetime.now()
while alarmnow.hour != int(hour) and alarmnow.minute != int(minute):
    time.sleep(1)
    alarmnow = datetime.datetime.now()
```